# How to add an infinite amount of variables in Python

Tags: python

A little bit of context for this: I am going to be a junior in high school next year and I thought it would be cool to code some equations for things I would be doing in school. I have done equations for algebra (solving for x in the quadratic equation and such), and I thought it would be cool to create some code for chemistry. I'm trying to figure out how to balance equations, and I was thinking I could enter in all of the amounts and using a certain key (let's say space) it would continue to the next part of the chemical equation. Here is basically what I was thinking.

```
reac1_chem1 = input("Enter the first chemical: ")
reac1_amount1 = input("Enter the amount of " + reac1_chem1 + " atoms: )
reac1_chem2 = input("Enter the second chemical: ")
reac1_amount2 = input("Enter the amount of " + reac1_chem2 + " atoms: )
```

I want to continue this process until space is entered in as a chemical. How would I make this process infinite? Is creating variables the way to go or should I make a list? Any suggestions would be appreciated! Let me know if this was in any way confusing and I can try to clear it up for you. Thanks!

Comment: A database/dictionary/list would be a good way to go about it. A dictionary maybe better as I am assuming the `Keys` i.e. the chemicals have unique amounts/values with that you can collect all their values and use a for loop to sum or keep track of the chemical amounts using the dictionary.

Comment: You probably want to use a list or other collection that fits the problem. You'll want to use a loop to fill it.

Comment: A couple people have been giving solutions, but I am pretty new to python, so some code would help clear up what you are suggesting

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary would be great:

```py
chemicals = dict()

index = 1
while True:
    chemical = input(f"Enter chemical {index}: ")

    if chemical == " ":
        break
    else:
        chemicals[chemical] = input("Enter the amount: ")
    
    index += 1

print(chemicals)
```

Comment: I am pretty new, so if you wouldn't mind me asking a couple of questions, I would appreciate it. What does dict() do? What does the f before "Enter... do? Thanks!

Comment: The `dict()` creates an empty Python dictionary. Dictionaries are a great way to store data, this way you could easily do `chemicals["MgCl2"]` to access the amount of MgCl2, and so on.

The `f` makes it a formatted string, i.e. everything inside curly braces in the string is treated as an expression.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to store the information in a dictionary of dictionaries, example as follows:

```
dct = {"ReactionNameOrID": {"ChemicalName1":"ATOMS", "ChemicalName":"ATOMS2"}}
```

You can then access the information like this:

```
dct.get("ReactionNameOrID").get("ChemicalName1")
#which will return: "ATOMS"
```

You could then use a class to store everything inside including the functions.

```
class Reactions():

    #initialize the dictionary
    def __init__(self):
        self.dict_reactions = {}

    #add a function to the class to add more reactions
    def add_chemical(self):
        reaction_name = input("Enter the reaction name/id: ")
        dict_chemicals = input("Enter the chemicals + atoms as dictionary: ")
        self.dict_reactions[reaction_name] = dict_chemicals

MyReactions = Reactions()
# Enter the reaction name/id: FirstReaction
# Enter the reaction name/id: {"H":100, "O":500}
MyReactions.add_chemical()
print(MyReactions.dict_reactions)
#{'FirstReaction': '{"H":100, "O":500}'}
```